# In SQL, how do I get all rows where a column's value is the lowest in the table?

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions

I am a newbie to SQL, I am using this query to look for the minimum value in the field weight of my table.

```
SELECT product_id, 
       MIN(weight) 
  FROM table 
 WHERE 1;
```

It does show one field with the min value, but only one? But I have many products with the same minimum weight. Is there a way I could specify that I need to show all other products?

Comment: You want to see products with the minimum weight value for the table?  If there's more than one, you want to see them all--correct?  For which database?

Comment: You do realize that your `where 1` is not doing anything, right?  You can remove it and it will still return exactly the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select * from table where weight = (select MIN(weight) from table)
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be what you're asking for:

```
SELECT product_id FROM table WHERE weight = (SELECT MIN(weight) FROM table);
```

As you might guess, this will select all `prodict_id`s where the weight is equal to the minimum weight in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which one exactly you want, but either of these should do the trick:

```
SELECT product_id, MIN(weight) FROM table WHERE 1 GROUP BY product_id
```

(List all product IDs and the minimum weight per product ID)

```
SELECT product_id, weight FROM table WHERE weight = (SELECT min(weight) FROM table)
```

(Find all product IDs where the weight equals the minimum weight)

```
SELECT min(weight) FROM table;
```

(Find the absolute minimum weight, and that's that)